# Check Permissions throwing SecurityException even though I am able to write

Tags: java, file-permissions, access-control

```
public void checkPermissionUsingAccessController(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(path, "write"));
            System.out.println("Passed");
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry no rights");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        UserPrivileges userPrivileges = new UserPrivileges();
                    userPrivileges.checkPermissionUsingAccessController(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        PropertiesExample example = new PropertiesExample();
        example.saveProperties("example");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
```

This prints: `Sorry no rights`

When I run this program, even though the AccessController tells this application doesn't have write permission, I am still able to write to the pwd. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong??

Comment: What version of Google Play Services are you using? Do also have any logs showing up in logcat?

Comment: @intj I am not using Google Play. Its just a simple code I wrote. PropertiesExample is my class that just stores a file by calling Properties.store